# What are the most secure read and write rules for anonymous authentication in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I have developed a web game in which no one needs to register. One person creates a room and then other people join the room using the room id created by the first person.

My structure goes like this

```
- games
    - game_uid
       - room_uid
       - players
       - messages
       - scores
    - game_uid
       - room_id
       - players
       - messages
       - scores
- rooms
    - room_uid : pin
    - room_uid : pin
```

I make the game_id same as the person's firebase auth_id(anonymous). So whatever happens in the game happens under the ref = games/game_id.

I changed my firebase rules to

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

As it was not working with the false. I want to know how safe is my firebase with these settings. Or is there any other rules for anonymous authentication. I don't want to setup login/signup as it is just a game and don't want to create login options.

i came to know about the wildcard locations, so if change my rules to

```
{
  "rules": {
    "games": {
          "$game_id": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null"
       }
     }
  }
}
```

will this be of any use?

Comment: Your database is completely unsafe with those rules.  Anyone with an internet connection can read and write all of the data.

Comment: What can be done so that a person can't read/write the data except its game_id?